# Why does one person hit "showers"?

Tags: word-usage

> “You get shit figured out?”
>
> “Yeah, I’m pretty sure I did. I’m just gonna hit the **showers**. I’ll be
>   back in a few,”

The person "I" hit the "showers", why does use the plural of "shower"?

Comment: The speaker is going to a place where there are lots of showers, like in a gym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiom originating from the fact, that in prison or at the gym, or at school, showers are not separated, but there are a couple of showers next to each other, so for example, the team after a football game "hits the showers" together. 
But also "hit the shower" is commonly used, so using plural form of this idiom by one person is just coming from slang.

Comment: I agree that "hit the showers" is a common idiom, but not that "hit the shower" (singular) is *commonly* used.  In fact I've *never* heard it used, except by those seemingly confused about the idiom.  Of course, now that I look it up, I see it's used with increasing popularity, so perhaps I'm just out of date.